# How to get string after write?

Tags: java

I have some logic that read content and write.
before I send it to client I want to remove some content

```
private void handGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, IFileStore file)
            throws IOException, CoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, JSONException {
        ....//set header
        OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8");
        out.write(EOL);
        out.flush();
        IOUtilities.pipe(file.openInputStream(EFS.NONE, null), outputStream, true, false);
        out.write(EOL + "--" + boundary + EOL); //$NON-NLS-1$
        out.flush();

    }

public static void pipe(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, boolean closeIn, boolean closeOut) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int read = 0;
        try {
            while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
        } finally {
            if (closeIn)
                safeClose(inputStream);
            if (closeOut)
                safeClose(outputStream);
        }
    }
```

now I want to get the result in the out or outputStream and want to replace some string how I can get the data and then How I can save it ?

Comment: show us what you tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacement for `outputStream` can be done like this (put it in try-block of your `pipe` method):

```
            // This method always replaces malformed-input and unmappable-character sequences with this charset's default replacement string.
            String str = new String(buffer, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            // Replaces each occurence of "replaceThis" with "", for regex use: replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)
            str = str.replace("replaceThis", "");
            // This method always replaces malformed-input and unmappable-character sequences with this charset's default replacement byte array
            byte[] replaced = str.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
                outputStream.write(replaced);
```

This is using UTF-8 charset, provided it is available. I don't know about performance, though.

I'm not sure what the `OutputStreamWriter` is used for but you could write the String to that using its `write(String str, int off, int len)` method

Comment: could we have short chat ?